# Verilog shift register of parameterized length

Tags: verilog

I am new in Verilog code. I have to do a problem in verilog code with a shift register. I searched before asking, but I didn't find something similar. Could someone please help me with some tips about creating the code in Verilog for this register?
Thank you! Have a nice day!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this might get you going:

```verilog
module DW03_shft_reg #(
// the parameterisable length of the shift register needs to be a parameter
    parameter LENGTH = 1              
  )(
      input [LENGTH-1:0] p_in,
      input s_in, load_n, shift_n, clk, 
      // this needs to be a 'reg' so that it can be assigned to by the 'always' block
      output reg [LENGTH-1:0] p_out     
  );

    // the template for sequential code with no asynchronous reset
    always @(posedge clk)               
        begin
          // implement the behaviour from the truth table here
          // the { , } (concatenation) operator is useful for shift registers
        end

endmodule
```

Comment: The real problem for me is that i don't understand the behavior of the shift register, i have searched online and i can find only the universal one on 4-bit or 8-bit. I don't understand the logic of the circuit. I have a truth table and some diagrams of signals. But i don't have the logic in my mind.

Comment: I have this part module DW03_shftreg_inst( inst_clk, inst_s_in, inst_p_in, inst_shift_n,
inst_load_n, p_out_inst );
parameter length = 4;
input inst_clk;
input inst_s_in;
input [length-1 : 0] inst_p_in;
input inst_shift_n;
input inst_load_n;
output [length-1 : 0] p_out_inst;
// Instance of DW03_shftreg
DW03_shftreg #(length)
 U1 ( .clk(inst_clk), .s_in(inst_s_in), .p_in(inst_p_in),
.shift_n(inst_shift_n), .load_n(inst_load_n), .p_out(p_out_inst) );
endmodule

Comment: To be honest, it is difficult to tell you any more without just telling you the answer. The missing lines in your `always` block are something like: `if (~load_n) p_out <= p_in; else if (~shift_n) p_out <= {p_out[LENGTH-2:0],s_in};` So, if `load_`n is asserted, the shift register is loaded with `p_in`; otherwise if `shift_n` is asserted, the register shifts (see how I have used the concatenation operator).  I say "something like" because I have not tested this. Your specification says nothing about the _direction_ of the shift and it says nothing about which has priority `shift_n` or `load_n`.

Comment: I also wonder why, in the code you gave in your comment, you are using old-fashioned, pre-2001 Verilog? All you are doing is instantiating my code in yours, but you have reverted to this old-fashioned style.

Comment: I have written the code as you gived me. The last part where it says //Instance of... It's the point to make the test bench.

Comment: Down i posted a link to the "wave signals" form. This is how my shift register needs to work.

Comment: Well - it looks like I guessed the spec correctly (usually a load would take priority over a shift and shift registers tend to shift left). If the code you posted in the comment is a testbench, how come it has ports? Testbenches don't usually have ports, because if they did you'd need another testbench to drive/sense those ports. Normally you'd start a testbench something like this: `module DW03_shftreg_TB;  // ie a module declaration with no ports`